# what is the difference in setting FontSize = 25 or 25pt?

Tags: wpf

What is the actual difference in giving fontsize in 25 and 25pt?. Why the 25pt is looking bigger in size?. So while handling font size which one to follow 25 or 25pt?

```
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock FontSize="25" >Kishore</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock FontSize="25pt" >Kishore</TextBlock>
    </StackPanel>
```

o/p

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [FontSize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textblock.fontsize%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) property defaults to pixels when a unit qualifier is not specified (in passing, note that Silverlight only supports pixels).

The `pt` unit qualifier means the value in specified in [points](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_%28typography%29#Current_DTP_point_system), a resolution-independent unit defined as 1/72 of an inch. That's why the resulting size is larger: for instance, on a WPF display surface, `25pt` is roughly equivalent to `33px`, because WPF always provides 96 [DPI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dots_per_inch) surfaces.

Answer (score 0):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textblock.fontsize.aspx

states "An unqualified value is measured in device independent pixels." which is the `px` unit